# Return two floats to previous activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am using `startActivityForResult` to show new activity(map Activity). In new activity i use `setResult`.

How I can return two float values to previous activity (longtitude,latitude from map Activity) ?

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
intent.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

you can then retrieve them from previous activity